# Testing and accepting User Input in Python using a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

What am I doing wrong?

```
valid = set(["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun","All"])
value = input("Enter the day of interest or all for all days. Valid Values are Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun,All: ")
count = 0

while count <= 3:
    if value in valid:
        print("Awesome!! You chose {}".format(value.title()))
        break
    else:
        count += 1
        pass
        print("Try Again")

else:
    print("Too many errors. Read the instructions and come back again when ready!! :-| ")
    exit()
```

So this works if I enter a valid value but if I test for a value outside the set, the else from the if loop ('Try Again') executes 3 times (setting the counter and then jumps to the else of the while loop.

I had wanted the input box to appear again and persist till either:
1. User entered the right value in 3 tries
2. Got a message and got booted out of the program returning them to command prompt.

Thanks in advance. Doing a tutorial project and completely stuck on this. Should I be using try/except? If so, would I still be able to set a counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow the user to enter input again. Place the input entering line below the Try again part.

```
print("Try Again")
value = input("Enter the day of interest or all for all days. Valid Values are Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun,All: ")
```

You also do not require the `pass` statement.

And please note that you're starting count from 0, that actually gives the user 4 chances, not 3. (Start with `count=1`)

Comment: Thank you so much, Sruthi!! That worked. I also edited out the <= 3 to < 3. It was giving me 4 turns originally.